# Is it possible to condition CanCan abilities on a date attribute range?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, cancan

Given a Rails model "Widget" with an attribute "date", is it possible to place a condition on a CanCan action authorization that requires the date to be later than the current time?  The [documentation](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/defining-abilities) shows how to specify a range for a numeric attribute:

```
can :read, Project, :priority => 1..3
```

... but it's not clear how this would apply to an open-ended range for another type (e.g. "> Time.now"):

```
can :some_action, Widget, :date => "????"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a block for conditions

```
can :some_action, Widget do |widget|
  widget.date.to_time > Time.now
end
```

If the block returns true then the user has that ability, otherwise he will be denied access.

Refer [this](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities-with-Blocks) for more info

Comment: Thanks! This almost worked out of the box, but the date needs to be converted to a time before it can be compared against time. I've proposed an edit reflecting that and accepted the answer.

Answer (score 1):

For newer versions of ruby (>= 2.6) and rails, a better solution is to use so-called infinite ranges:

```rb
can :some_action, Widget, date: Date.current..
```

This still works with CanCanCans `accessible_by` operation and can be combined with other `can` permissions into a single query as necessary.